# jQuery count divs and hide some... dynamic?

Tags: jquery

I have come across the following code that looks at divs contained inside divWiz and separates them into two halves which the user can switch between.

This is all well and good, but what about if I wanted to make it more dynamic? By that I mean throwing in some pagination.

Using the code below you see that I am generating 50 divs. The code splits them into two even sets of 25 that can be swtiched between using the Next and Previous buttons.

[See jsfiddle for working example](http://jsfiddle.net/qWsga/)

Now lets say I want to limit the number of shown divs to 10 instead of 50. I have no idea how to get the navigation between these sets of 10 to generate.

Basically, instead of Next and Previous, I want to see Page: 1, 2, 3, 4, etc

HTML

```
<input value=" Next " type="button"/>
<input value=" Prev " type="button"/>
<input value=" Show All " type="button"/>
<div id="divWiz"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
var i, cutoff, total = 50;
for(i=0; i<total; ++i)
    $(document.createElement("div")).html(i).appendTo("#divWiz");

cutoff = total/2;

$("#divWiz > div").hide();
$("#divWiz > div:lt("+cutoff+")").show();

$("input[value=' Next ']").click(function() {       
    $("#divWiz > div").hide();        
    $("#divWiz > div:gt("+(cutoff - 1)+")").show();
});

$("input[value=' Prev ']").click(function() {       
    $("#divWiz > div").hide();        
    $("#divWiz > div:lt("+cutoff+")").show();    });    

$("input[value=' Show All ']").click(function() {       
    $("#divWiz > div").show();        
});        
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you look at one of the slew of pagination plugins. A couple of lightweight examples:

http://geckohub.com/jquery/simplepager/

http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/jquery-quick-pagination/

More:

http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/

Comment: None of these will do.

My intent is to use the solution found to implement it within my wordpress loop and couple it with a custom toggling system so that when a post is toggled, a class "ignore" is attached to the div. The pagination would then refresh itself to ignore the toggled posts and pull in replacement posts.